# Drawing multiple plots on the same figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
plot3(X,Y,Z,'r');
hold on
plot3(Xs,Ys,Zs,'g');
```

Why do I only get one plot? If I try to draw them separately, both draw just fine.

Comment: It looks fine, and it should work. Can you please expand a little with a small sample data that can replicate the error, a rough image of what you expect, and what you get.

Comment: Works for me with  `X = [1 2 3]; Y = [1 2 3]; Z = [1 2 3]; Xs = 4+[1 2 3]; Ys = 4+[1 2 3]; Zs = 4+[1 2 3];`

Comment: This could be also a scaling issue. What are the ranges of all your variables?

Comment: @EBH first set I can't even predict - I'm messing with Bezier curves and have to use some stupid formula that does not even work, the second set just describes random points inside 0:5,0:5,0:5 cube.

Comment: Type `[min(X(:)) max(X(:))]` before plotting, and see what is the range of your values with respect to `Xs`. do so for `Y` and `Z` as well, and see if their range is from the same order, or one is **very** small compared to the other so you can't see him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague. It's not clear if you want to plot 2 sets of data on the same axes (for that your code is fine), or you want to plot to different axes on the same figure.

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
X = 0:0.1:100;
Y = sin(X);
Z = cos(X);
Xs = 0:0.1:100;
Ys = cos(X);
Zs = sin(X);
```

For the first option you would write:

```
plot3(X,Y,Z,'r');
hold on
plot3(Xs,Ys,Zs,'g');
hold off
```

and get:

[image]

and for the second option you would write:

```
subplot 211
plot3(X,Y,Z,'r');
subplot 212
plot3(Xs,Ys,Zs,'g');
```

and get:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I want to do what you've done on the first picture, but for some reason I only see one of my (x,y,z,'') tuple being drawed. I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @BarsiktheCat which one of them do you see? the first or the second?

Comment: the first one  @EBH

Comment: @BarsiktheCat so you probably have a scaling problem. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501211/drawing-multiple-plots-on-the-same-figure/42502755?noredirect=1#comment72150458_42501211) and see what you get

Comment: weird, I though matlab documentation said that if you do it like that, you'll get proper scaling automatically. Anyway, this problem cleaerly shows that my algorithm is wrong, so I'll try to fix it first before tweaking plots.